Prefix hash array: understanding OpenCL slowdown
I'm trying to speed up building a hash prefix array with OpenCL 3.0.
Starting with v = [v[0], v[1], v[2], ... ], I want to build:
pref = [v[0], B * v[0] + v[1], B**2 * v[0] + B * v[1] + v[2], ... ].
I'm not aware of any library function (in boost.compute for example) that can achieve this (the prefix scan requires an associative operator).
My approach (~6 times slower than the serial variant) consists of 4 kernels, and uses 4 buffers (v (input), pref (output), and two scratchpads, spad1 and spad2):

copy_spad: copy a device buffer in another buffer.
shr_spad: right shift a device buffer into another buffer.
mul_spad: multiply every element in a device buffer by a number.
add_pref: add a device buffer into another.

For example, if v would have three elements, then my implementation would work like this:
pref : [v1, v2, v3]
spad1: [ ?,  ?,  ?]
spad2: [ ?,  ?,  ?]

Round 1:                                  |   Round 2:
                                          |
copy_spad(pref, spad1):                   |   copy_spad(pref, spad1):
pref : [v1, v2, v3]                       |   pref : [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad1: [v1, v2, v3]                       |   spad1: [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad2: [ ?,  ?,  ?]                       |   spad2: [ 0,        B*v1,        B*v2]
                                          |
shr_spad(2**0, spad1, spad2):             |   shr_spad(2**1, spad1, spad2):
pref : [v1, v2, v3]                       |   pref : [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad1: [v1, v2, v3]                       |   spad1: [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad2: [ 0, v1, v2]                       |   spad2: [ 0,           0,          v1]
                                          |
mul_spad(B**1, spad2):                    |   mul_spad(B**2, spad2):
pref : [v1,   v2,   v3]                   |   pref : [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad1: [v1,   v2,   v3]                   |   spad1: [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]
spad2: [ 0, B*v1, B*v2]                   |   spad2: [ 0,           0,     B**2*v1]
                                          |
add_pref(spad2, pref):                    |   add_pref(spad2, pref):
pref : [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B*v2 + v3]     |   pref : [v1,   B*v1 + v2,   B**2*v1 + B*v2 + v3]
spad1: [v1,          v2,          v3]     |   spad1: [v1,   B*v1 + v2,             B*v2 + v3]
spad2: [ 0,        B*v1,        B*v2]     |   spad2: [ 0,           0,               B**2*v1]
                                          |

Effectively, the main implementation looks like this:
for (int i = 0; i < full_n; i += n) {
   ///we have multiple batches, each of size n.
   queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(pref_d, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * n, all_nos.data() + i);

   B = 27;
   for(int step = 1; step < n; step <<= 1, B = (long)B * B % mod) {
       copy_spad(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), n, pref_d, spad1_d).wait();
       shr_spad(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), n, step, spad1_d, spad2_d).wait();
       mul_spad(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), n, B, mod, spad2_d).wait();
       add_pref(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), n, mod, pref_d, spad2_d).wait();
   }

   queue.enqueueReadBuffer(pref_d, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * n, pref_h.data());
}

One batch size is n = 25'000, and there are 4000 batches: full_n = 100'000'000.
I need the kernels to be blocking, i.e. the next one doesn't run until the previous one finishes. I assume that .wait() is necessary.
The kernel implementations:
void kernel copy_spad(int n, global int *v, global int *spad1) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    spad1[i] = v[i];
}

void kernel shr_spad(int n, int amt, global int *spad1, global int *spad2) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    spad2[i] = (i < amt? 0: spad1[i - amt]);
}

void kernel mul_spad(int n, int B, int mod, global int *spad) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    spad[i] = (long)spad[i] * B % mod;
}

void kernel add_pref(int n, int mod, global int *pref, global int *spad1) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    pref[i] += spad1[i];
    pref[i] = (pref[i] >= mod? pref[i] - mod: pref[i]);
}

Without taking the setup into consideration, the OpenCL operations take the following amount of time (on average, over all batches):



Operation
Time (%)




enqueueWriteBuffer
5.46%


enqueueReadBuffer
5.79%


copy_spad
18.6%


shr_spad
18.9%


mul_spad
19.5%


add_pref
29.7%



I assumed that add_pref takes that much more because of two possible accesses to pref[i], but refactoring didn't improve the percentage.
I don't know how to further optimize the kernel operations. I am sure that OpenCL transmits commands to the GPU:
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
if (platforms.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "No platforms found.\n";
    return 0;
}

cl::Platform default_platform = platforms[0];
std::cout << "Using platform: " << default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";

std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
if (devices.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "No devices found.\n";
    return 0;
}

cl::Device default_device = devices[0];
std::cout << "Using device: " << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "\n";

Produces:
Using platform: NVIDIA CUDA
Using device: NVIDIA GeForce MX150

I am not sure if OpenCL uses all 384 available CUDA cores, and I don't know how to check for that.
I declare the kernels like this:
cl::compatibility::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> copy_spad(cl::Kernel(program, "copy_spad"));

I declare the number of wanted device threads like this:
cl::NDRange global(n);

I declare the device buffers like this:
cl::Buffer pref_d(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * n),
           spad1_d(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * n),
           spad2_d(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * n);

So very little device memory is used (under 1 MB). As a result, I don't think that the program is memory bound.
There is visible overhead because of .wait() (~45% of the runtime is spent there).
The full implementations can be found here.
Am I using the command queue properly? I am not sure if I need to do any further setup for OpenCL for my GPU. For example, boost.compute implementations of sort or radix sort are much slower than their serial counterparts.

"So very little device memory is used (under 1 MB). As a result, I don't think that the program is memory bound." That isn't how you determine if something is memory bound. You determine it by looking at the ratio between memory accesses and compute (see arithmetic intensity). If at all, the small problem size hints at under-utilization of the hardware causing less than optimal throughput.

@paleonix: Sorry, you're right. Computation is definitely not the most intensive part here (e.g. % diff between mul and copy/shr). I tried a bigger batch size (n = 1e6, 1000 batches), only ~4.5X slower now. In practice, I need to use pairs of hashes (esentially ulong2) - the slowdown goes up to 9X. I need to scan packet data, so n = 25'000 is (unfortunately) generally an overestimate.

"not sure if OpenCL uses all 384 available CUDA cores" Generally, you can use Nvidia Nsight for that. However it does not support OpenCL yet (the proposed alternatives are not always simple to install/use regarding the target machine -- especially on HPC clusters with limited rights).

It seems you launch a lot of kernels and those are quite trivial. The overhead of kernel start might be significant not to mention it should increase the memory pressure (they all seem rather memory bound). Can't you merge them? Accessing registers is far more efficient than accessing memory (even the L1/L2 cache). Per-block copies can be more efficient than global copies (thanks to shared memory if explicitly used, or the L1 cache otherwise).

In add_pref, you do several unneeded memory operation and I am not sure the compiler will optimize it. You can put pref[i] in a register so to avoid doing multiple memory read.

By the way, IDK what your CPU is but the MX150 is a 7-year-old low-end low-power notebook GPU so it is far from being great. Its RAM only reach 48 GiB/s and its L2/LLC cache is 0.5 MiB, so not even 1 MiB! A 7-year old mid-end notebook CPU with 2x good DRAM should reach ~40 GiB/s, and 1 MiB should clearly fit in the L3/LLC cache which should reach >100 GiB/s anyway. If you want your GPU to be faster, you need to avoid memory access like the plague so to make kernels compute-bound (not easy).

@JérômeRichard Thank you for the responses, I cut down the copy kernel and merged the other three. Now it's just ~1.8X slower than serial. I am trying to merge the O(log n) kernel calls as well, not entirely sure that it will be correct. Using a register in add_pref didn't change anything (tried it in the gist linked at the bottom of the post), seems that the compiler optimized it anyway. The CPU indeed reaches ~37.5GB/s (i5-8250U). I will check the Nsight alternatives out. TY again! I will hopefully come back with another merge.

Your CPU code is sub-optimal due to the long dependency chain of instructions, especially the modulus. You can move away the modulus of the dependency chain so to reduce the overhead of the instruction latency and increase the number of instruction per cycle. I think it is possible to make the (sequential) code at least twice faster with that (maybe up to 3 but certainly no more).

On the GPU side, mod is not a constant and this can have a huge impact on performance. Compilers can often generate a much better code when the right part of a modulo is a compile-time constant. This is the case on your CPU implementation. So to be fair you should do the same on the GPU one. The same thing is true for B (though on GPU the impact should be small if any while multiplication by a constant are generally faster on x86 CPUs than multiplication by non-constant).

Here is an example of more optimized CPU code moving away some instructions of the long dependency chain : https://godbolt.org/z/nqrnW8814 . This (untested) code should be twice faster than your code.

@JérômeRichard Thank you for the example. I forgot about the non-const mod, indeed without it the slowdown is ~1.6X now. I was wrong about merging the O(log n) kernel calls, I don't think it can be done. In my non-toy example (link) I am using a fixed modulo (M61 prime) with two randomly chosen bases (so it is expected that B**2 won't fit in 64 bits). The kernel is still not compute bound. I will add the hash-cut kernel now, if I won't get an improvement I will try to optimize the CPU code like you instead.

Ok. If B**2 do not fit in a 64-bit int, then isn't there is a possible overflow in the ucrrent code? I mean if the initial value is in the range [0;B[, then once multiplied by B it can overflow before the modulus? Another strategy to unroll the loop would be to compute (B**2)%mod to avoid overflow maybe.

@JérômeRichard I am using a custom mul function that takes advantage of some M61 properties to circumvent overflow, you can see it in the previous link (or better this one: link). I think that the serial code can be written better, but at the moment I have a ~2.7X speedup with the gpu:-), owing to now actually computing O(nlogn) hashes after the prefix scan. TY, I will try some loop unrolling as well.

@catalyst I am not sure to fully understand your code but I guess you talk about mul2x isn't it? The loop calling this function seems better than the one provided in this post. The latency is already mitigated relatively well since you compute 2 items at a time (it seems technical details but this is critical for performance on CPU -- details matter). Thus, unrolling should not help at much as it does on the previous code. On the CPU side, you can try to parallelize the code on your 4 cores. SIMD vectorization is also possible (like on GPU) but it is certainly significantly more complex.
